# Set default value for rank_feature field type

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene, opensearch

I'm performing a **rank_feature query** and there is a possibility that the fields that I will rank i.e **bid field** (please below) won't be available.

I wonder if there is a way **to set a default** for **bid** if the field is not present.

For example, here is my **document mapping**

```
PUT /tier-sort-2
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "popularity_scores": {
        "type": "nested",
        "properties": {
          "score": {
            "type": "rank_feature"
          },
          "study_field": {
            "type": "text"
          }
        }
      },
      "bid": {
        "type": "rank_feature"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here are my **test documents**:

```
POST _bulk
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"1"}}
{"title":"Job 1","popularity_scores":{"score":"0.105", "study_field":"45"}}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"2"}}
{"title":"Job 2","popularity_scores":{"score":"0.06", "study_field":"45"},"bid":"50"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"3"}}
{"title":"Job 3","popularity_scores":{"score":"0.099", "study_field":"45"},"bid":"25"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"4"}}
{"title":"Job 4","popularity_scores":{"score":"0.155", "study_field":"45"},"bid":"5"}
{"index":{"_index":"tier-sort","_id":"5"}}
{"title":"Job 5","popularity_scores":{"score":"0.028", "study_field":"45"},"bid":"100"}
```

Here is my **query**:

```
GET tier-sort/_search
{
  "size": 100,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "popularity_scores",
            "query": {
              "rank_feature": {
                "field": "popularity_scores.score",
                "boost": 1
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "rank_feature": {
            "field": "bid",
            "boost": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, for document with **_job="1"**, the **bid field** is not present.

Is there a way to set a default value for that field i.e **bid="50"**

Thanks in advance!